# Perl multithreading and foreach

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am writing a simple Perl script that should run other Perl scripts simultaneously. I don't know how to make the main program wait for running threads. Sleep IS NOT a suitable solution because of many reason. This is my "main" script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use threads;
main:
{
    if ($#ARGV == -1) { usage(); exit(1); }
    my $hostname = $ARGV[0];
    my $thrssh = threads ->create(\&ssh, $hostname);
    my $thrdns = threads ->create(\&dns, $hostname);
    my $thrping = threads ->create(\&ping, $hostname);
    my $thrsmtp = threads ->create(\&smtp, $hostname);
    my $thrproxy = threads ->create(\&proxy, $hostname);
}
sub ssh {
    threads->detach();
    my $hostname = @_;
    #print "SSH\n";
    #LAUNCH SSH SCRIPT
}
#OTHER SUBROUTINES...
sub proxy {
    threads->detach();
    my $hostname = @_;
    #print "PROXY\n";
    #LAUNCH PROXY SCRIPT
}
```

If I try to run this script the first thing I can notice is that prints are "sequential", I thought text was messed up but maybe Print is exclusive I don't know. Main problem is that the last two subroutines don't have time to be executed.

```
SSH
DNS
PING
Perl exited with active threads:
2 running and unjoined
0 finished and unjoined
0 running and detached
```

If I use *join* instead of *detach* the subroutines become "sequential", for example if I put a sleep in sub ssh other threads will wait before starting. I want them to be parallel and the main program to close ONLY when all threads are finished, any help?

**I actually have another question, if I have to run multiple threads in a foreach cicle when I am supposed to join them? ie:**

```
my $thrssh;
foreach $mynode ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    #...
    $thrssh = threads ->create(\&ssh, $port, $hostname);
    #...
}
$thssh->join();
```

**Is that right?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to  `join` all your threads *from the main thread* after they have all been started. Don't `detatch` if you don't want the interpreter to exit while the threads are still running.

```
...
my $thrssh = threads ->create(\&ssh, $hostname);
my $thrdns = threads ->create(\&dns, $hostname);
...
$thrssh->join();
$thrdns->join();
...
```

Regarding your edit: no, it's not right. You need to keep a reference to each thread you create, otherwise you can't join them.

Do something like:

```
my @thrs;
foreach $mynode ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    #...
    $thrssh = threads ->create(\&ssh, $port, $hostname);
    push @thrs, $thrssh;
    #...
}
$_->join() for @thrs;
```