# Parallel::ForkManager makes subroutine 1000x slower

Tags: multithreading, perl, parallel-processing, fork

I have a subroutine, which I've serially optimized as much as *I* can, approximately like

```
sub overlap {

    my $hash_reference = shift;   # pass the hash to the subroutine
    my %h = %{ $hash_reference }; # refer to the hash as %h
    my $standard = shift;         # this is the key that will be compared against
    my $compared = shift;         # this is the key being compared
    my $start_index = 0;          # this will continually be increased
                                  # to save computation time

    # I want to parallelize here

    foreach my $s ( 0 .. scalar @{ $h{$standard}{end} }-1 ) {
        foreach my $c ( $start_index .. scalar @{ $h{$compared}{end} }-1 ) {
            ... # abbreviated for minimal working example
        }
    }

    return ($standard_indices_met_in_compared, \@overlay);
}
```

This is a slow subroutine.  I run it thousands of times in about 12-14 minutes, but running this again and again wastes time.

I regularly use `Parallel::ForkManager` for system processes, but this doesn't work well here.

Implementation of `Parallel::ForkManager` looks like

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw();
my $manager = new Parallel::ForkManager(2);
foreach my $s ( 0 .. scalar @{ $h{$standard}{end} }-1 ) {

    foreach my $c ( $start_index .. scalar @{ $h{$compared}{end} }-1 ) {
        $manager->start and next;
        ... # abbreviated for minimal working example
    }

    $manager->finish;
}

$manager->wait_all_children;      # necessary after all lists
```

I've looked at threads and such, but do not see how to apply here.

I have looked at [Perl multithreading and foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119244/perl-multithreading-and-foreach) and the Perl documentation for threads, and numerous other sources, but I don't see how I can apply what has been done before in this case.  Everything I see looks like it is for system commands only.

I want to write to a shared array and scalar, with no system commands. In case I'm missing something, please tell me.

How can I parallelize this `foreach` loop inside a subroutine?

Comment: In short, in many ways.  In principle, you can just `fork` in the loop, for instance, so for every iteration you get a child process which executes the code in it. (But with "_thousands_" you'd need more to do.) It also depends on what you need/want to do with output from children, etc.  But, what do you mean that `P::FM` "_doesn't work well here_" ?

Comment: Hi zdim, Parallel:ForkManager made the loop about 1000x slower.  When I normally run Parallel:ForkManager, I see linear increase on cpu.  I'll try "fork"

Comment: Hang on -- there is a good chance that something is in fact not right with how exactly you use `P::FM` there.  It shouldn't do that.  If you have so many to run, then you'd need _precisely_ a thing like `P::FM`, to restrict the number of forks at a time.  Perhaps show us a crux of how you use `P::FM`?

Comment: One thing I can think of is that you have the whole `P::FM` setup inside of loops ...?  That would be bad. In short, make the object _outside_, and have only the child code inside. You only want _one_ object for the whole thing.

Comment: Re "*I don't see how I can apply what has been done before in this case*", It's trivial to use threads to do the same thing as P::FM, but you said P::FM is no good for you, so this could very well be no good for you either. I'm not going to waste time guessing what you want. Please specify what problems you are facing with P::FM. "*This doesn't work well here*" is far from an adequate problem description.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "It doesn't work well" is not a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: ikegami - "It doesn't work well"  means P:FM makes the program run *slower* please think for a few seconds before you go saying things like"I'm not going to waste time guessing what you want" I'm trying to parallelize a foreach loop, just like the title says.  Please spend some time reading the description before saying rude things like that.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about speed, so don't go chastising me for not assuming that was the problem. Besides, that's still nigh-useless information. Show what makes it slower! Is it doing too little per process? Is it using too much memory? You have yet to show us the problem!!! It's you who needs to think for a second. Don't pretend that you are trying to parallelize the code cause you already achieved that. Figure out what problem you are trying to solve and give us some information that would help us help you solve that problem. Do so by fixing your question to contain this information

Comment: having ->start inside the loop and ->finish outside it is going to make each forked process complete that loop, definitely not what you want.

Comment: though you need to think about where you want to parallelize; how long does each iteration of the inner loop take, vs each iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: and what output is needed from the sub processes; how are @overlay and $standard_indices_met_in_compared set?

Comment: It would be useful to know what exactly you are trying to parallelize, because not all tasks go faster if the resources are actually interdependent.  There is always going to be overhead associated with running more processes or threads.  For CPU intensive tasks, it may be best to match the number of CPU cores with the number of work processes.  If you are trying to have 1000 processes update the same table in a database, you may be hitting contention issues.  If you are trying to read 1000 files in memory, you may be hitting IO issues.  Etc.  There is no magic bullet that fixes all problems.

Comment: I cleaned up the post a bit in terms of formatting. There was a stray `}` in the first code snippet.

Comment: My best guess would be putting `$manager -> finish;` inside the loop, instead of outside would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you really trying to parallelize with a maximum of two processes only? If so, this may be the source of the perceived slowness.

There will always be an overhead associated with parallelization. You cannot guarantee a 10x speed-up if you parallelize over 10 processes.

I suggest you open up the maximum number of processes to something more reasonable and try again. If this does not help, it may be due to:

- hardware limitations
- something about the loop you are trying to parallelize that is forcing sequential execution (e.g. writing to the same file, DB table, updating a semaphored or shared variable...)

Comment: IO is the classic thing that doesn't parallelise well. A disk spins only so fast, and by adding contention from concurrent, out of order reading, you decrease the throughput.

Comment: Hi Zaid, thanks for your thoughtful response.

I have tried 2, 4, and 8 cpu in P::FM but everything runs much slower than just serial.

the subroutine works in a foreach statement, I'm iterating through a hash-array.

Sobrique- the subroutine uses no I/O, just a hash-array.  All variables must be shared.  Maybe threads is the right way to go, I'll look into it.

Comment: Zaid, all processes read from the same array, and write to the same variable.  Perhaps this process is not easily parallelized, you may be correct.

Comment: the key point is the last in Zaid's answer: "something about the loop you are trying to parallelize that is forcing sequential execution (e.g. writing to the same file, DB table, updating a semaphored, shared variable...)"

Answer (score 1):

Once we got to see the [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) part, I'd like to address a direct error in what is shown, already noted in a comment by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth).

With loops only indicated for clarity, and with a bit more meaningful limit, you have

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new(8);

foreach my $s ( ... )
{    
    foreach my $c ( ... ) 
    {
        $manager->start and next;    # 
        # code                       # WRONG
    }                                # Module: Can't fork inside child
    $manager->finish;                #
}
$manager->wait_all_children;
```

Let's see what this attempts to do.

A child is forked inside of the inner loop. But it exits *outside of it*, meaning that it runs the whole loop. So each child would also execute the line that creates new children, along with the parent. That would be a real mess, with a cascade of children and with a wrong partition of work between them.

But the module just doesn't allow this, throwing an error. Is your real code different than shown?

Now consider

```
foreach my $s ( ... ) 
{    
    $manager->start and next;     # child forked

    foreach my $c ( ... ) 
    {                             # Whole inner loop
        # code                    # run by one child
    }                             # for one value of $s

    $manager->finish;             # child exits
}
```

A fork happens outside of the inner loop and the child proceeds to run the whole loop, with the current value of `$s`.  The parent skips to the next iteration of the outer loop and forks another child, which runs the inner loop for that, next, value of `$s`. Each child runs the whole inner loop for subsequent values of `$s`. So the iterations of the outer loop are executed in parallel.

This is what you want.  So change your code to do this and see how it goes.

To repeat what has been said, not all code benefits equally from being run in parallel. Some code cannot at all run correctly in parallel, and some may suffer a noticable performance drop.